# Recursive Formula for D_m

Tags: number-theory

We consider the following definition of "new" numbers $D_m.$ We define them by the generating function

$$G(t) = \frac{-t}{e^t + 1 + e^{-t}} = \sum_{m \geq 0} D_m \frac{t^m}{m!}$$

The first part of the question was to compute the values of $D_m$ for $0 \leq m \leq 5.$ I did this correctly, the corresponding values are: $D_0 = 0, D_1 = -\frac{1}{3}, D_2 = 0, D_3 = \frac{2}{3}, D_4 = 0, D_5 = - \frac{10}{3}.$

The second part of the question was showing that $D_m = 0$ if $m$ is even. This is obvious as G(t) is an odd function so all the even terms in its Taylor expansion will vanish.

We wish to find a recursive formula for $D_m$ in the spirit of the recursive formula for $m \geq 1,$ $$B_m = - \frac{1}{m+1} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{m+1}{k}B_k$$

where $B_k$ is just the k-th Bernoulli number.

So, $$-t = (1 + e^t + e^{-t})G(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}a_nt^n \sum_{m \geq 0} D_m\frac{t^m}{m!}$$
$$= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}a_n \sum_{m \geq 0}D_mt^{m+n} = \sum_{l \geq 0} t^l(\sum_{m = 0}^{l} \frac{a_{l-m}}{(l-m)!}\frac{1}{m!}D_m).$$
We know $$1 + e^t + e^{-t} = 3 + 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n)!}t^{2n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n!}t^n.$$ Therefore, $a_0 = 3, a_n = 0$ for odd n and $a_{2n} = 2.$
When $l = 1$ we get $$\sum_{m = 0}^l \frac{a_{1-m}}{(1-m)!} \frac{1}{m!} D_m = 3D_1.$$
When $l \geq 2$ we get $\sum_{m=0}^l \frac{a_{l-m}}{(l-m)!} \frac{1}{m!} D_m = 0.$ If l is even, we get $$0 = 2 \sum_{m=0}^l \frac{1}{(l-2m)!}\frac{1}{(2m)!}D_{2m} = \frac{2}{l!}\sum_{m=0}^{l} \binom{l}{2m} D_{2m}$$ but this doesn't say anything as we already know $D_{2m}$ is zero.

I'm concerned with the case where $l \geq 2$ is odd. And we sum over m, I had a look at the solutions and it says the following:

$$0 = 2 \sum_{m=0}^{\frac{l-3}{2}} \frac{1}{(l-2m-1)!}\frac{1}{(2m+1)!}D_{2m+1} + \frac{3}{l!}D_l =$$
$$= \frac{1}{l!}(\sum_{m=0}^{\frac{l-3}{2}} \binom{l}{2m+1}D_{2m+1} + 3D_l). (*)$$

Rewriting the last formula with $l = 2m + 1$ and $m \geq 1:$
$$D_{2m + 1} = - \frac{2}{3} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{2m+1}{2k+1}D_{2k+1}$$

I have three main questions concerning this:

1. Firstly, why do we sum over $\frac{l-3}{2}$? Where does that come from?
2. Where does the term $\frac{3}{l!}D_l$ come from here?
3. I can't see how the final recursive equation follows from (*)

Comment: Please, use MathJax also in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason we sum over $l-3$ in the equation $\sum_{m=0}^{l} a_{l-m}(l-m)!m!D_m = 0$ is because we have a factor of $(l-m)!$ in $a_{l-m}$, and we want to simplify it to $(l-2m)!$ using the identity $(l-m)! = (l-2m)! (l-2m+1)\cdots(l-m)$.

The term $3l!D_l$ comes from evaluating $\sum_{m=0}^{l} a_{l-m}(l-m)!m!D_m$ at $m=l$. Since $a_0 = 3$ and $a_{2n}=2$ for all $n\geq 1$, we have $a_{l-m}=0$ for odd $l-m$, which means that $a_{l-m}(l-m)!m!D_m=0$ for odd $m$. Hence, we only need to consider even $m$, which gives us the term $3l!D_l$ when $m=l$.

Finally, to see how the recursive equation for $D_{2m+1}$ is obtained, we substitute $l=2m+1$ and divide both sides of the equation $\sum_{m=0}^{l} a_{l-m}(l-m)!m!D_m = 0$ by $l!$, which gives
$$
\sum_{m=0}^{l} \frac{a_{l-m}}{(l-m)!m!}\frac{l!}{l!}D_m = \sum_{m=0}^{m} \frac{a_{2m+1}}{(2m+1)!}\frac{(2m+1)!}{l!}D_{2m+1} + \frac{3D_l}{l!} = 0.
$$
Using $a_{2n}=2$ and $a_0=3$, we get $\frac{a_{2m+1}}{(2m+1)!} = \frac{(-1)^m}{2^{2m+2}(m+1)}$ and $\frac{a_1}{1!}=1$, which gives
$$
\frac{a_{2m+1}}{(2m+1)!} = \frac{(-1)^m}{2^{2m+2}(m+1)},\quad
\frac{a_1}{1!} = 1,\quad
\frac{a_{2n}}{(2n)!} = \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n+1}}\quad\text{for }n\geq 1.
$$
Substituting these into the equation above and simplifying, we get
$$
D_{2m+1} = -\frac{2}{3}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \binom{2m+2}{2k+1}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{2k}}D_{2k+1}.
$$
This is the desired recursive formula for $D_{2m+1}$.

Comment: I don't really get your explanation for (i), the sum is over $\frac{l-3}{2},$ not $l-3$